# SoftDeletes on model breaks dynamic properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, soft-delete

TLDR: When the `SoftDeletes` trait is included in my parent model, I no longer get soft deleted instances of the parent model as a dynamic property of the child. How can this be done?

---

I have defined a couple of basic models, like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Post");
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }

    public function scopePending(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->whereNull("pending");
    }
}
```

In my controller, I want to list pending posts, so I do this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::pending()->get();
        return view("post.index", ["pending"=>$posts]);
    }
}
```

And finally, in my view:

```
@foreach($pending as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}<br/>
    {{ $post->user->name }}<br/>
@endforeach
```

This results in an exception being thrown, "Trying to get property of non-object" with the line number corresponding to where I try to output `$post->user->name` for users which have been soft deleted.

How can I have these dynamic properties include soft deleted items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the related user model has been soft-deleted, that's why the related user is not loaded.

Define the relation like in the code below and you'll be always able to fetch a user regardless if they have been soft-deleted or not:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User")->withTrashed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you do so

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User")->withTrashed();
}
```

you will no longer available to use dynamic access to user relation, because dynamic access expects that relation method returns `BelongsTo` instance, which returns by `belongsTo` method of `Eloquent` class. But `withTrashed` returns `Builder` instance.

**EDIT**

I was wrong, thanks @patricius for being guided on the right path (in comments).

Comment: This is not correct. `$this->belongsTo("App\User")` will return a `BelongsTo` object. When you then call `withTrashed()` on the `BelongsTo` object, it falls down into the `__call()` method on the extended `Relation` object. The `__call()` method will call `withTrashed()` on the underlying `Builder` object, but it will return the `BelongsTo` object to the original caller. Therefore, `$this->belongsTo("App\User")->withTrashed();` will return a `BelongsTo` object.

Comment: @patricus, thanks for explanation, I don't know what to do now. Should edit/delete my answer or keep it as is?

Comment: Up to you. Though the comment provides useful information, some people don't make it to the comments and just read the answer. You can either just delete your answer, or edit it to show that it is not correct, and you're only keeping it due to the useful information from the comment. You're more than welcome to add the information to your answer if you decide to keep it.